# One of my edits is accepted but I am still getting "too many pending edits" warning

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Yesterday, I suggested editing for a few questions and after that, I got the warning that I had too many pending edits and I had to wait until previously suggested edits were accepted.

Today, one of my edits (from yesterday) was accepted, so I thought I can edit one more question, but when I try to edit one today, I am still getting a "too many pending edits" warning although one was accepted today.

Could somebody explain to me what is the cause here?

Comment: No you still had 5 edits pending. The limit is slightly waived if submitting both a tag wiki and excerpt at same time, so you were likely just over your limit. One of your edits has just been reviewed so you should be down to 4/5 now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I have to chime in for a sec to say that please do not make trivial edits to tag wikis (such as *only* adding the missing definite article) - there are too many trivial edits in the system without them, too few reviewers for tag wikis (both because of the rep requirements and the frustrating review workflow). What makes things worse is that tag wikis/excerpt edits are jumbled with normal suggested edits... Try creating wikis for tags about the tech you know, have experience in - this will be of great help for the community.

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks for your suggestion! I will definitely try to keep it in mind the next time.

Comment: Not to pile on too much, but in addition to what Oleg mentioned, when [you are revising a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30801809) that contains a signature, please do not fix the signature. Instead, please *edit out* the signature. See [Are taglines and signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) for more information.

Comment: @Ian I just viewed the link you shared about signatures and taglines. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I went through your list of edits and approved a few of them. I should note that some of your suggestions were overly simple edits that only fixed minor problems. Be sure you're trying to fix questions that are on-topic and MRE. Simple edits to fix grammar and spelling might seem useful, but people have to review your edits and there is an overall queue limit (which we often hit). Also, if a question is poor enough to warrant your mentioning help center pages, please flag the question for closure.

Comment: @Machavity I have to begrudgingly note that [approving minor edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30817207) overlooking noise, tag duplication in titles, error formatting, and other grammatical errors does not send the right message to editors...

Comment: @OlegValter I understand, but the ones I did approve were borderline enough to let through. I did decline one for only adding spaces

Comment: @Machavity no issue with other approvals, only with that specific one - it really worries me to see a binding approval on it, that edit is not in line with editing guidelines...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As per the [Rate Limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/) guide, you can only submit an edit when you have *less than* 5 pending edits. That does not, however, mean you can't have more than 5.

One of your edits was on a tag wiki and excerpt, which actually counts as **two** edits, not one. When you submitted this edit you were most likely at 4 pending edits, and so 2 were submitted, taking you up to 6 pending edits. As such, before you can submit another edit you need 2 edits to be reviewed.

From the linked answer:

> #### Editing
>
> ...
>
> - At most 5 [pending suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202) per editor (20 on beta sites)
>
>   - Limit is partially waived if submitting a tag wiki and excerpt suggested edit at the same time (which counts as two edits) - if the user only has space for one more pending edit, both edits will still be allowed, but **they cannot submit another suggested edit until two of their pending edits** are approved (i.e. they're no longer exceeding the limit)

Answer (score 6):

You're allowed a maximum of [5 pending suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/188189) and that's what you have right now.

You've made the following suggestions that are all awaiting approval...

- [3 in the last two hours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8993341/muhammad-mohsin-khan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1)
- One 21 hours ago i.e. yesterday
- Your final one is a tag wiki suggestion. They tend to take longer because the rep required to review them is higher. That one was suggested on January 3rd.

Given you've suggested at least one wiki edit, perhaps you edited the wiki and the excerpt which [can put you over the limit temporarily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/684990).